# Select Canvas Node using go.Diagram

Tags: selenium, canvas, gojs

I am able to click on the required canvas node, but also needed to select the node prior to clicking '+' button attached to it

```js
//get a reference to the diagram object
const diagram = go.Diagram.fromDiv(document.getElementsByClassName("diagram-component")[0])
    
//using the diagram object find a node by name
const node = diagram.findNodesByExample({text: "capeutil"}).first()
    
//once you have the node you can expand it with the following command
node.findObject('ButtonButton').click(null, {part:node});
```

Need to help to select node by text

Selenium implementation

```
public void test_node_selection(String nodeName){
        sleep(5);
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) context.getDriver();
        js.executeScript(
                "const diagram = go.Diagram.fromDiv(document.getElementsByClassName('diagram-component')[0]);" +
                        "const node = diagram.findNodesByExample({text: '" + nodeName + "'}).first()" +
                        "diagram.select(node);");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a reference to a node, you can select it by calling [Diagram.select](https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Diagram.html#select)

```js
diagram.select(node);
```

Note that this clears any other selection the Diagram may have.

Comment: Tried, not work, getting error as  org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Unexpected identifier

Comment: this is assuming that both `diagram` and `node` are non-null values from your code above. Otherwise I don't know why you would get such an error. I suggest you try everything outside of Selenium first.

Comment: Hi thanks, it's work, but the desired result is not achieved, actually, it must be clicked in order to show the data, , is this possible?

Comment: Maybe instead what you want is clicking event simulation, see: https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/Robot.html

Comment: I am not able to digest this script , can you please help with how to use this ?